# Add Class to div when click counter reaches 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now when you click inside the div, the counter decreases by 1. How do I make it stop at 0?
Also when it reaches 0 how can I add a class?

I want the overlay to be enabled once the click counter reaches 0.
If there is a better way to disable the div box1 after the clicks reach 0. We can try it that way.

```
$( function() {
   $('.box').click( function() {
     var num = $(this).find('.num');
     num.text( parseInt(num.text()) - 1 );
   });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwn8xbdv/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than searching DOM and parsing HTML on each click, I'd cache both element and its value:

```
var $box = $('#box1'),
    $num = $box.find('.num'),
    limit = $num.text();

$box.click(function() {
    $num.text(--limit);
    if (limit === 0) {
        $('.overlay').show();
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wp6Lfrc8/).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('.box').click( function() {
    var num = $(this).find('.num');
    val = parseInt(num.text()) - 1;
    if (val > 0){
        num.text(val - 1);
    } else {
        $(".overlay").show();
        // add your class here.
    }
    num.text( val );
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwn8xbdv/1/)